# Git version control for Drupal CMS based projects and MySQL Database

Tags: git, drupal, version-control, content-management-system, cpanel

I am hosting a website using the Drupal/CMS ( in a shared hosting service provider ). I often have to update the site with different modules and its very time consuming to back up each and every time I make changes to the site, different modules etc manually. I was wondering if there is a way to set the git (or equivalent) to version control my Drupal CMS source as well as the MySQL database? How to set a git based version control system for Drupal/CMS based project running under the cPanel in a shared web hosting service? How can I merge /synch my source/database on a development server with the source and database of a live/deployed server (where user may be updating contents)?

Comment: I use Git for all my Drupal projects. Services like GitHub often suggest a .gitignore file for common systems like Drupal. Here's an [example](https://github.com/archfizz/thenationalforum.com/blob/master/.gitignore), though you may also like to add the modules directory to the the list

Answer (score 0):

Yes. you can certainly use Git. You can upload your folder to the Git repository. After each update to your site, you can cut a tag which will save version of those files in release.

For more on tagging with version numbers, refer to https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141973/how-do-you-achieve-a-numeric-versioning-scheme-with-git

For setting up the Git repo, refer to:

- https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git
- http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup